# Magento: redirect to the same page after language selection?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

When a client click on one of the language icons/flags in a Magento eCommerce site, it will "for example" redirect to: `http://www.magento-site.com/?lang=en` to change to the language the client asked for, the problem is when a client chooses a language, Magento redirects the client to the home page after setting up the new language, this causes the client to lose the page he/she was originally in, so let's say if a client was in `http://www.magento-site.com/customer/account/login` after changing the language he/she will be in `http://www.magento-site.com/` "The home page" not the page he/she was in "`http://www.magento-site.com/customer/account/login`", what to do to redirect the client to the page he/she was in after changing the language.
PS: I have changed nothing in the configuration it's Magento 1.4.

Comment: This question is _extremely_ difficult to read and comprehend, consider revising?

Answer (score 1):

```
$_lang->getCurrentUrl()
```

in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/switch/languages.phtml

However, this happens by default, so sounds like you've gone wrong somewhere with the installation or customisation.

Example at http://demo.magentocommerce.com/catalog/category/view/s/ebooks/id/37/?___store=default&___from_store=pl_PL

Comment: The problem is that my Magento is using `?lang=LANGUAGE` instead of `?___store=default&___from_store=pl_PL` and is redirecting to home page whenever a language is selected/clicked.

Comment: There should be a store view for each language, so use the store code. Look at the default demo set up as an example.